# Font differences between Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, font-size

I bet this is a pretty common question, which I think can't be solved, but at least I'll try.

**Check this image out:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dddNm.jpg]

Go to the following URL for a larger image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dddNm.jpg

**HTML code:**

```
<div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 60px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">TEXT GOES HERE</div>
```

As you can see, the font doesn't look the same. Is there any way to solve this problem?

- Internet Explorer version: 9.0.8112.1641 64-bit Edition
- Mozilla Firefox version: 13.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the exact HTML used to create the text in the image? Also, can you hardcode the font-weight and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I've tried font-weight already, both numeric and alfabetic. The size of the text is changed, but it's still differences between IE and FF. The HTML code I pasted in the topic is everything I'm currently using. (this is just for testing purposes, of course)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one way to solve the problem: Make it an image.

How text is rendered depends on a lot of factors, like the fonts installed, operating system, rendering calibration, font smoothing and rendering parameters. If any of those parameters differ, the result differs.

If you examine your image, you will see that the browsers use different parameters for font smoothing, and other parameters may also differ.

You simply can't expect an identical result when rendering text in different browsers.

Comment: Yeah exactly what I thought from the beginning. Case closed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) is a jQuery plugin that can be used to kern the letters with precision. Results may vary

Comment: "with precision. Results may vary"... Funny.