# Ugly font rendering in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Is there any workaround to ugly font rendering in Internet Explorer - Windows?

```
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

[image]

[Here is a 100% crop:](http://d.pr/i/qFoS+)
Left: IE
Right: FF

Comment: Is it just me or does the IE one look better?!

Comment: Are you testing this on a Windows system that actually has Helvetica Neue or Helvetica?  Which of the texts in the screenshot are affected by the `font-family` setting?  What are the other settings for the texts, such as font size?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela for example "Kúpiť", I think the font weight is too bold. Iam trying on a Windows 7, no additional font were installed. font-weight: bold; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) . The site: http://bit.ly/SrP5w8

Comment: Look at the €-Sign... These are not the same fonts... Are you even using a @font-face?

Comment: I guess Nirazul is right. Right side FF preview is Mac's preview i guess, Because it's seems in right one font is helvetica and in left one it's arial.

Comment: @Tarun no, it is same machine. On Mac the text rendering is fine.

Comment: Can you test both(IE/FF) in developer tool? Because as Nirazul said if you see Price, facebook icon text. It's seems they are different fonts. Or can you share link, so that i can check.

Comment: The site: is here bit.ly/SrP5w8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is very complicated and gives different CSS rules to different browsers. But the font rendering difference is ultimately very simple, and in this sense the question might be regarded as a duplicate of e.g. [Font differences between Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849849/font-differences-between-mozilla-firefox-and-internet-explorer).

The difference can be demonstrated in a very simple setup where the CSS code is reduced to the following:

```
a {
 padding: 1px 2px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background: rgb(38, 127, 234);
 font: 13px Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

So it’s just Arial Bold in 13px size with a certain blue background and in white color. On IE, some strokes look thicker than on Firefox, due to differences in font rendering algorithms, and there is nothing you can do about it now or in the foreseeable future, except that this may lead you into reconsidering the font and style choices.

The following is what you get (produced on Windows 7; Firefox on the left, IE on the right):

[image]

If you magnify it so that pixels becomes discernible, you’ll see rather many differences:

[image]